# Commerce Authoring GetBulkPrice method Problem

Tags: sitecore-commerce

I followed the documentation about Sitecore Commerce installation. I finished configuring everything, then try to open storefront. It returns error something like "HTTP Error 502.3 - Bad Gateway
The specified CGI application encountered an error and the server terminated the process." and requested url is " http://localhost:5000/api/GetBulkPrices"

This url is by default Commerce Authoring service. Then I tried with postman and send request and after 2min it returns same error. So that I changed Authoring request time out to 20min and it stills running. I don't thing this will take that much.

P.S: I can send request to other api methods and returns with success result. It seems configuration are correct. Does anyone any idea why it is taking too long?

Comment: This can be a little bit tricky to debug. Can you give an example of a API method that does work? Did you try any of the Catalog API methods?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem got fixed by re-doing a part of the Commerce Authoring Service setup:

> Run the **Bootstrap** on the service, which loads the environments from
>   the data/environments directory in the physical location of the IIS
>   service

Use a browser and call http://localhost:5000/commerceops/Bootstrap().

After this process was done, the website works.